# How does the geospatial $nearSphere operator interact with LineString and Polygon

Tags: mongodb, geojson

According to the documentation, a [2dSphere geospatial index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) can also be used for complex GeoJSON shapes like LineString's and Polygon's which consist of multiple nodes.

When you search a field filled with such complex shapes with [$nearSphere](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/nearSphere/) for proximity to another GeoJSON object (which can potentially also be a complex shape), how will the distance of these shapes be calculated?

Will it compare the closest nodes of the shapes? The most distant nodes? Some average of the nodes? The closest point on any of the edges of the shape?

Comment: $nearSphere returns geospatial objects in proximity to a point - can you clarify what you mean by comparing shapes?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky $nearSphere takes a radius. Geospatial objects can be polygons or line-strings. I want to know what happens when these polygons are partly inside the radius of $nearSphere and partly outside of it.

Comment: $nearSphere takes a point and optionally maxDistance. So you cannot use it to get all shapes near a shape, only shapes near a point.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky That's obvious, but $nearSphere also automatically sorts the results by distance. How does it calculate which shape is nearer than another when some of its points are further away and some are closer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$nearSphere` operator only allows you to specify a point (center of the "sphere" you can define by providing `maxDistance` parameter).  Therefore the only meaningful answer can be about how shapes are sorted nearest to furthest.

The answer is that all shapes which have equidistant "nearest" point are going to be sorted ahead of shapes which have their nearest point further.  In other words, a distance between a point and a shape is the distance between a point and the nearest point on the shape.

We can see that by running a variant of `$nearSphere` which is [`$geoNear`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/#dbcmd.geoNear) command as it returns calculated distance which we can then examine.

Our sample data:

```
> db.near.find()
{ "_id" : 10, "loc" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 5 ], [ 5, 5 ], [ 5, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 11, "loc" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [ [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 5 ], [ 5, 5 ], [ 5, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ] ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 12, "loc" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 6 ], [ 6, 6 ], [ 6, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 13, "loc" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 6 ], [ 6, 6 ], [ 6, 0 ], [0, 0 ] ], [ [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 5 ], [ 5, 5 ], [ 5, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ] ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 14, "loc" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 6 ], [ 6, 6 ], [ 6, 0 ], [ 0, 0 ] ], [ [ 0.1, 0.1 ], [ 0.1, 5 ], [ 5, 5 ], [ 5, 0.1 ], [ 0.1, 0.1 ] ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 15, "loc" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [ [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1 ], [ 1, 1 ], [ 1, 0 ], [0, 0 ] ],  [ [ 0.1, 0.1 ], [ 0.1, 0.5 ], [ 0.5, 0.5 ], [ 0.5, 0.1 ], [ 0.1, 0.1 ] ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 16, "loc" : { "type" : "LineString", "coordinates" : [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0.1, 0.1 ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 17, "loc" : { "type" : "LineString", "coordinates" : [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0.1 ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 18, "loc" : { "type" : "LineString", "coordinates" : [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 0.1, 0 ] ] } }
```

Our results with $nearSphere:

```
{ "_id" : 16, "loc" : { "type" : "LineString", "coordinates" : [  [ 0, 0 ],  [  0.1,  0.1 ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 18, "loc" : { "type" : "LineString", "coordinates" : [  [ 0, 0 ],  [  0.1,  0 ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 14, "loc" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [  [  [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 6 ], [     6,  6 ],    [   6,  0 ],    [   0,  0 ] ],  [   [   0.1,    0.1 ],  [   0.1,    5 ],    [   5,  5 ],    [   5,  0.1 ],  [   0.1,    0.1 ] ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 13, "loc" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [  [  [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 6 ], [     6,  6 ],    [   6,  0 ],    [   0,  0 ] ],  [   [   1,  1 ],    [   1,  5 ],    [   5,  5 ],    [   5,  1 ],    [   1,  1 ] ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 15, "loc" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [  [  [ 0, 0 ], [ 0, 1 ], [     1,  1 ],    [   1,  0 ],    [   0,  0 ] ],  [   [   0.1,    0.1 ],  [   0.1,    0.5 ],  [   0.5,    0.5 ],  [   0.5,    0.1 ],  [   0.1,    0.1 ] ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 12, "loc" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [  [  [ 0, 0 ],  [  0,  6 ],  [  6,  6 ],  [  6,  0 ],  [  0,  0 ] ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 17, "loc" : { "type" : "LineString", "coordinates" : [  [ 0, 0 ],  [  0,  0.1 ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 10, "loc" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [  [  [ 0, 0 ],  [  0,  5 ],  [  5,  5 ],  [  5,  0 ],  [  0,  0 ] ] ] } }
{ "_id" : 11, "loc" : { "type" : "Polygon", "coordinates" : [  [  [ 1, 1 ],  [  1,  5 ],  [  5,  5 ],  [  5,  1 ],  [  1,  1 ] ] ] } }
```

And running [$geoSphere](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/#dbcmd.geoNear) command, we can confirm the distance from the point to the shapes (omitting the coordinates for space considerations):

```
> db.runCommand({geoNear:"near", near: {type:"Point", coordinates:[0,0]}, spherical:true})
[
    {
        "dis" : 0,
        "obj" : {
            "_id" : 16,
            "loc" : {
                "type" : "LineString"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "dis" : 0,
        "obj" : {
            "_id" : 18,
            "loc" : {
                "type" : "LineString"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "dis" : 0,
        "obj" : {
            "_id" : 14,
            "loc" : {
                "type" : "Polygon"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "dis" : 0,
        "obj" : {
            "_id" : 13,
            "loc" : {
                "type" : "Polygon"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "dis" : 0,
        "obj" : {
            "_id" : 15,
            "loc" : {
                "type" : "Polygon"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "dis" : 0,
        "obj" : {
            "_id" : 12,
            "loc" : {
                "type" : "Polygon"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "dis" : 0,
        "obj" : {
            "_id" : 17,
            "loc" : {
                "type" : "LineString"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "dis" : 0,
        "obj" : {
            "_id" : 10,
            "loc" : {
                "type" : "Polygon"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "dis" : 157424.6238723255,
        "obj" : {
            "_id" : 11,
            "loc" : {
                "type" : "Polygon"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

As you can see, the distance of every shape (except for last one which started at [1,1]) to the point [0,0] was 0, even though the shapes all differed in size and shape.  Within the documents which have the same distance to the specified point, the order is not defined.  What that means is that even if it seems deterministic, it is not guaranteed to be the same.